# How to upload multiple files with Django into a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, file, upload

How to upload multiple files with Django into a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: what did you try? googling is not enough

Answer (score 2):

One of the way how to do it is to use `ForeignKey`:

```
class Album(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True)

class Images(models.Model):

  image = models.ImageField(u upload_to='images/', blank=True)
  album = models.ForeignKey('Album', blank=True, null=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.image.name
```